# Jquery delay on fadeout

Tags: jquery, delay, fadeout

I have this code that changes the opacity of the div on hover.

```
$("#navigationcontainer").fadeTo("slow",0.6); 

$("#navigationcontainer").hover(function(){ $("#navigationcontainer").fadeTo("slow",
    1.0); // This sets the opacity to 100% on hover },function(){ 

$("#navigationcontainer").fadeTo("slow",
    0.6); // This sets the opacity back to 60% on mouseout });
```

I want to have a delay before setting the div back to 0.6 opacity how would i do this

Answer (score 52, accepted):

With jQuery 1.4, you have a method called [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), which takes an integer representing ms you want to delay

```
$("#navigationcontainer").delay(500).fadeTo("slow", 0.6);
```

Half a second delay

Answer (score 2):

use set timeout with a callback to the functionality you want and a delay that you want.

```
$("#navigationcontainer").fadeTo("slow",0.6); 

$("#navigationcontainer").hover(function(){ $("#navigationcontainer").fadeTo("slow",
    1.0); // This sets the opacity to 100% on hover },function(){ 


var delay = 1000;
setTimeout(function() 
    { 
        $("#navigationcontainer").fadeTo("slow",
            0.6); // This sets the opacity back to 60% on mouseout });

    },
    delay
)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$("#hover_me").hover(function() {
                $("#target_div").fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
           }, function() {
                $("#target_div").delay(800).fadeTo("slow", 0.6);
           });
```